# Parsing a nested JSON object

Tags: json, rust, serde-json

I'm trying to parse a JSON file with the following loose format using `serde_json` in Rust:

```json
{
  "Source_n": {
    "Destination_n": {
      "distance": 2,
      "connections": [
        {
          "color": "Any",
          "locomotives": 0,
          "tunnels": 0
        }
      ]
    }
...
```

where `Source` and `Destination` can be any number of keys ([Link to full file](https://github.com/AGnias47/ticket-to-ride-graph-analysis/blob/main/mattgawarecki-ticket-to-ride/usa.routes.json)).

I've created the following structs in an attempt to deseralize the JSON:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct L0 {
    routes: HashMap<String, L1>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct L1 {
    destination_city: HashMap<String, L2>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct L2 {
    distance: u8,
    connections: Vec<L3>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Clone)]
struct L3 {
    color: String,
    locomotives: u8,
    tunnels: u8,
}
```

When I try to read the JSON as an L0 object I get a panic on this line:

```rust
let data: L0 = serde_json::from_str(&route_file_as_string).unwrap();
```

Panic:

```
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.01s
     Running `target/debug/ticket-to-ride`
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error("missing field `routes`", line: 1889, column: 1)', src/route.rs:39:64
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
             at /rustc/59eed8a2aac0230a8b53e89d4e99d55912ba6b35/library/std/src/panicking.rs:517:5
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/59eed8a2aac0230a8b53e89d4e99d55912ba6b35/library/core/src/panicking.rs:101:14
   2: core::result::unwrap_failed
             at /rustc/59eed8a2aac0230a8b53e89d4e99d55912ba6b35/library/core/src/result.rs:1617:5
   3: core::result::Result<T,E>::unwrap
             at /rustc/59eed8a2aac0230a8b53e89d4e99d55912ba6b35/library/core/src/result.rs:1299:23
   4: ticket_to_ride::route::route_file_to_L0
             at ./src/route.rs:39:20
   5: ticket_to_ride::route::routes_from_file
             at ./src/route.rs:44:33
   6: ticket_to_ride::main
             at ./src/main.rs:6:5
   7: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
             at /rustc/59eed8a2aac0230a8b53e89d4e99d55912ba6b35/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:227:5
```

I've been able to read the JSON as a `HashMap<String, Value>` object, but whenever I try to start working at the lower levels I get an error. It seems to be looking for a key named `routes`, but what I actually want to just a nested HashMap, similar to how you can read a JSON in Python in a nested fashion.

Any advice on how to proceed? Is what I'm attempting reasonable with this library?

Comment: As the error says (`"missing field `routes`"`), you are asking to deserialize an `L0`, which consists of just a `routes` element, but the string from which you try to deserialize is missing that element. The way you tell serde which element should be deserialized to which struct member is by giving them the same name.

Comment: You should either add `#[serde(transparent)]` to the two structs containing hash maps, or use `#[serde(flatten)]` on the hash map fields.

Comment: Also checkout [`#[serde(rename = "…")] `](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#rename). Or `serde_json::Value`, if you don't want rust structs for your JSON.

Comment: I think you could also directly deserialise to a `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, L2>>` without defining L0 and L1. Possibly with an alias for convenience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Sven Marnach says in their comment, add `#[serde(flatten)]` to create the HashMap from data that uses keys as JSON fields:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct L0 {
    #[serde(flatten)]
    routes: HashMap<String, L1>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct L1 {
    #[serde(flatten)]
    destination_city: HashMap<String, L2>,
}
```

Comment: Still working through parsing the JSON, but this has gotten me past my current blocking point. Thank you! I wasn't aware of `#[serde(flatten)]`

Answer (score 2):

Functioning code parsing the referenced JSON is below. The `demo` function executes the parsing.

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::fs;
use std::clone::Clone;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct L1 {
    #[serde(flatten)]
    destination_city: HashMap<String, L2>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct L2 {
    distance: u8,
    connections: Vec<L3>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Clone)]
struct L3 {
    color: String,
    locomotives: u8,
    tunnels: u8,
}

fn route_file_to_hashmap(fpath: &str) -> HashMap<String, L1>  {
    let route_file_as_string = fs::read_to_string(fpath).expect("Unable to read file");
    let data: HashMap<String, L1> = serde_json::from_str(&route_file_as_string).unwrap();
    return data;
}

pub fn routes_from_file(fpath: &str) -> HashMap<String, L1>  {
    let route_file_as_map: HashMap<String, L1> = route_file_to_hashmap(fpath);
    return route_file_as_map;
}


pub fn demo() {
    let routes: HashMap<String, L1>  = routes_from_file("usa.routes.json");
    println!("---Cities---");
    for (k, _) in &routes {
        println!("{}", k);
    }
    let chicago: &HashMap<String, L2> = &routes.get("Chicago").unwrap().destination_city;
    println!("---Destinations from Chicago---");
    for (k, _) in chicago {
        println!("{}", k);
    }
    let to_omaha: &L2 = chicago.get("Omaha").unwrap();
    println!("---Data on Route to Omaha---");
    println!("Distance: {}", to_omaha.distance);
    print!("Connections: ");
    for c in &to_omaha.connections {
        println!("{} ", c.color);
    }
}
```